# Generating 2-by-2 tuples from list and finding the duplicated tuples in python

Tags: python, pandas, tuples

I am a beginner in Python and I am having trouble generating and identifying duplicates on tuples on my dataFrame.

First I have this list of userid:

```
'userid': ["us1", "us2", "us1", "us2", "us4", "us4", "us5", "us1", "us2"]
```

And I want to generate 2-by-2 tuples at the order the userid are in the list, so it would be:

```
[('us1', 'us2'),
 ('us2', 'us1'),
 ('us1', 'us2'),
 ('us2', 'us4'),
 ('us4', 'us4'),
 ('us4', 'us5'),
 ('us5', 'us1'),
 ('us1', 'us2')]
```

But the tuples I arrive are this ones (and I don't understand why):

```
 [('us1', 'us2'),
 ('us2', 'us1'),
 ('us1', 'us4'),
 ('us4', 'us2'),
 ('us2', 'us5'),
 ('us5', 'us4'),
 ('us4', 'us1'),
 ('us1', 'us2')]
```

Here is my code:

```
   d = {'id': ["a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a"], 'id2': ["b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b"], 'userid': ["us1", "us2", "us1", "us2", "us4", "us4", "us5", "us1", "us2"], "time": [1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 7, 6, 8, 9]}
    df_test = pd.DataFrame(data=d).sort_values('time')
    df_test.groupby(['id','id2']).agg(lambda x: x.tolist()).reset_index()
    test2 = list(zip(df_test.userid[:-1], df_test.userid[1:]))
    zipped_list = test2[:]
    list(test2)
```

-> In addition, my next step will be finding duplicates on this tuples and extracting them for a new list, so in the case of the tuple:

```
    [('us1', 'us2'),
     ('us2', 'us1'),
     ('us1', 'us2'),
     ('us2', 'us4'),
     ('us4', 'us4'),
     ('us4', 'us5'),
     ('us5', 'us1'),
     ('us1', 'us2')]
```

Should be the list `[('us1', 'us2'), 3]` because is the only tuple that appears duplicated and the '3' is to say that appears 3 times this duplication.

Therefore I cannot find my error on generating the tuples on the order I want nor having any idea on how to find the duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us do `frozenset` + `value_counts`

```
pd.Series(list(map(frozenset,zipped_list))).value_counts()
(us2, us1)    3
(us1, us4)    2
(us2, us5)    1
(us5, us4)    1
(us2, us4)    1
dtype: int64
```

If only need the list reorder

```
l=list(map(frozenset,zipped_list))
```

Or we can do `numpy`

```
np.sort(zipped_list,axis=1).tolist()
[['us1', 'us2'], ['us1', 'us2'], ['us1', 'us4'], ['us2', 'us4'], ['us2', 'us5'], ['us4', 'us5'], ['us1', 'us4'], ['us1', 'us2']]
```

Update : you `sort_values` first , so we need `sort_index` back

```
list(zip(df_test.userid[:-1].sort_index(), df_test.userid[1:].sort_index()))
[('us1', 'us2'), ('us2', 'us1'), ('us1', 'us2'), ('us2', 'us4'), ('us4', 'us4'), ('us4', 'us5'), ('us5', 'us1'), ('us1', 'us2')]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, it helps a lot!! But on this case the input are being the tuples in the wrong order. As I explain in the post I would like to have them in the order as they appear in the list, so there it would be no repetition of the tuple (us1, us4) for example. Do you know also how can I achieve this?

Comment: @CatarinaNogueira `list(map(frozenset,zip(df_test.userid[:-1], df_test.userid[1:])))
`

Comment: Thank you! But I used exactly this, so changing my code where I do the zip we have: df_test['tuples']=  df_test.apply(lambda x: list(map(frozenset,zip(df_test.userid[:-1], df_test.userid[1:]))), 1). and the order that I explain in the post is not maintained, it's still the same order as in your answer, for example :(

Comment: @CatarinaNogueira your question is not clear, in my mind , change it after create and during create yield the same result

Comment: The thing is, if I change after counting the pairs, I will have 2 for the pairs (us1, us4)  for example, that is not the case. I want to generate tuples as I explained in the post. Another way of generating the tuples I want is: [(k,v) for k,v in (zip(df_test.userid,df_test.userid[1:]))], this works, but I couldn't manage to use this way as a column on my dataFrame, so I was trying using Zip, but Zip do not generate the same tuples...

Comment: If I use this way: df_test['tuples']=  df_test.apply(lambda x: [(k,v) for k,v in (zip(x.userid,x.userid[1:]))], 1) it do not work, but if I do separated from the dataFrame, this way:  [(k,v) for k,v in (zip(df_test.userid,df_test.userid[1:]))], it works, but I wanted to have on the dataFrame. That's why I was trying just Zip (but I can't use Zip on the way I am using because the resulted tuples are not being the same as on the other way, with the (k,v) for k,v in (z...))

Comment: Thanks!! Now it works!! One thing still, when I then create a column on the dataFrame for the tuples:  
df_test['tuples']=  df_test.apply(lambda x: list(zip(df_test.userid[:-1].sort_index(), df_test.userid[1:].sort_index())), 1). and after apply your code like this pd.Series(list(map(frozenset,list(df_test.tuples)))).value_counts(). it do not work, I got this as answer: ((us4, us1), (us1, us2), (us2, us5), (us4, us2), (us5, us4), (us2, us1), (us1, us4))    1 

Do you have any ideia why or what I could change for make this work? Because I wish I could keep all columns on the dataframe

Comment: @CatarinaNogueira tolist no list pd.Series(list(map(frozenset,df_test.tuples.tolist()))).